# UIModalPresentationCurrentContext and willRotateToInterfaceOrientation

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uiinterfaceorientation, autorotate

I have a modal view controller (let's call it the popup view controller) presented over my main view controller. At some point, I need so see the main view controller behind the popup. Therefore, I set the  `modalPresentationStyle` property to `UIModalPresentationCurrentContext` before presenting the popup view controller.

So what happens is that when the device orientation changes while the popup view controller is modally presented, the `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:` and `didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:` methods are not called. `supportedInterfaceOrientations` is called amd returns the good value. The rotation is enabled, the supported orientations are correctly set. The popup conIt actually works if I change 'modalPresentationStyle' to the default value, everything works fine, except that obviously I do not see the main view controller behind.

I should add that the main view controller only supports portait, while the popup above it supports all orientations.

On an iOS 5.1 device, the `willRotate` and `didRotate` methods are correctly called. It is only on the iOS 6 device that they are not.

Did anybody encountered a similar issue or already needed to display a transparent multi-orientation view controller modally above a single orientation view controller?

Comment: I got the same issue in an app i'd like to work on iOS6+. Have you ever found a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Do this...

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: (UIInterfaceOrientation) interfaceOrientation {
    UIDevice* thisDevice = [UIDevice currentDevice];
    if (thisDevice.userInterfaceIdiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return interfaceOrientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft;
    }
}
```